# Use earthdistance Postgresql extension in HQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, earthdistance

I am facing a problem with the [earthdistance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/earthdistance.html) extension of PostgreSQL.

Following [this](http://rodush.com/en/2013/09/postgres-and-earthdistance-extension/) guide, I have added the following extensions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

I tried to run the following SQL query from Postgres command line and everything works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.463444, -3.637716), 2000) @> ll_to_earth(table.lat, table.lon)
```

When I try to run the same query in HQL, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [Select 1 from table WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.463444, -3.637716), 2000) @> ll_to_earth(table.lat, table.lon)]
! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:250) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[logistics-statemachine-1.0.jar:na]
...
```

which tells me that HQL dialect does not recognise the installed Postgres extension.

Was anybody able to use this operator with HQL?

Answer (score 0):

The exception will be gone when the @ is taken off. Have you turned on the hibernate log to see the converted sql.